# Outlook img tag is not giving me the correct attachment id

Tags: outlook, office-js, outlook-addin, office-addins, outlook-web-addins

Im trying to create a new outlook add-in that can extract the email content as html, and extracting the email content is working fine `Office.context.mailbox.item.attachments`

But my problem right is, If there an img tag include to the content. It will give me like this kind of img tag

`<img class="x_w-1378 x_h-886" size="349452" data-outlook-trace="F:1|T:1" src="cid:9ea35d14-aa1e-47d6-9c5b-b31ced143981" style="max-width:100%">`

`<img width="643" height="359" id="x_Picture_x0020_1" src="cid:image001.png@01D8A327.B5A0B590" style="width:6.6979in; height:3.7395in">`

I know there's an isInline properties and i can extract the base64 of the attachment.

Now question is, How would i know, if this img tag is for this attachment and vice versa? Like there's no indicator in img tag like this

[image]

`<img id="AQMT12tasFGA....."  src="cid:image001.png@01D8A327.B5A0B590" style="width:6.6979in; height:3.7395in">`

Answer (score 0):

Mime Content-Id header is used for In-line attachments, see https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2392.txt for more information. Be aware, you can use EWS to get content ID values of attachments from Office web add-ins.